# What is this decoration called that's found around ceilings and doors?

Tags: single-word-requests, image-identification

What is this decoration called that's found around ceilings and doors, as shown in the images below?

[image]

[image]

Comment: On a ceiling, it's called crown moulding.

Comment: @jimm101 in Brit it is a cornice

Comment: @WendyG or coving, if it is uniform (as per the photograph)

Comment: You have a rope-twist moulding around the largest wooden panel.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because these are completely unrelated items that can't be covered by one term. The second one is structural.

Answer (score 4):

In general, those are *moldings*, also spelled *moulding*.

The one around the top of a wall is called a *crown molding*.

The particular shape used in that example makes it an (somewhat elaborated) [*ogee molding*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogee).

A molding slightly lower on the wall is called a *picture molding* or *picture rail* because it can be used to hang pictures from.

A molding about 3 feet above the ground is called a *chair rail* because it is (possibly) used to prevent the backs of chairs damaging the wall.

I don't know if there's a special name for the molding used on the doors. It could possibly be called a *panel molding* because it is used to visually separate the panels of those doors from the *rails* and *stiles* (the members of the frame that holds the panel).

Comment: It should be noted that in the US this is more generically known as "trim".

Comment: The moulding you call a 'chair rail' is also called a 'dado rail', at least inth UK.

Comment: @BoldBen, I haven't heard that one. But I would expect some regional variation.Someone in Boston might call it differently than someone in South Carolina.

Answer (score 3):

Both of these shapes can be generically described as **millwork**.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millwork_(building_material)

There are specific terms related to the position of the millwork in the overall fabrication, and terms related to the design of the millwork itself, but **millwork** covers all of these.

Comment: +1  but To be fair, this answer is a bit like someone posting a picture of a croissant and asking what it is and being told that it can be generically described as a baked good.

Comment: True, but faced with water biscuit and an eclair, what other choice is there?